# Adding Padding to line chart - data in anychart to display the line properly

Tags: javascript, css, linechart, anychart

I am using Line Charts Library from ANYCHARTS to display some dynamic data(data fetched from csv file). 
I am facing some issues when the data is 100%. The line does not display properly. I tried adding padding to the line chart configuration but it adds padding to whole chart rather than just giving padding to the data-line.
I wish if someone could help me on this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc46y.png)

Here is the code if it helps;

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
var dataSet = anychart.data.set(AnyData);
var Q6_Trend_AnyChart = anychart.line();
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.animation(true);
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.padding([15, 20, 5, 20]);
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.title();
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.yScale().minimum(0);
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.yScale().maximum(100);
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.contextMenu().itemsFormatter(function(items) {
// Disable save as image option
// delete about and separator 
delete items["full-screen-separator"];
delete items["about"];
delete items["anychart-credits"];
delete items["share-with"];
delete items["select-marquee-start"];
// return modified array
return items;
});
var seriesData_1 = dataSet.mapAs({'x': 0, 'value': 1});
var series_1 = Q6_Trend_AnyChart.line(seriesData_1);
series_1.name('');
series_1.hovered().markers()
.enabled(true)
.type('circle')
.size(4);
series_1.tooltip()
.position('right')
.anchor('left-center')
.offsetX(5)
.offsetY(5);
series_1.stroke("3 white");
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.tooltip().format("\nPercent:{%Value}%");
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.background().fill("transparent");
var labelsx = Q6_Trend_AnyChart.yAxis().labels();
labelsx.fontSize(12);
labelsx.fontColor("#fff");
labelsx.useHtml(true);
labelsx.fontWeight(600);
var labels = Q6_Trend_AnyChart.xAxis().labels();
labels.enabled(false);
series_1.markers(true);
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.legend()
.enabled(false)
.fontSize(13)
.padding([0, 0, 10, 0]);
// set container id for the chart
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.container(id);
// initiate chart drawing
Q6_Trend_AnyChart.draw();
});
}
```

if I increase the top padding from 15px to 45px in the given code, it results this; but still the line is not displaying perfectly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iCT5.png)

Answer (score 0):

The scale max means the top edge of the data plot. When the yScale maximum is auto-calculated chart adds a gap as a default. This allows avoiding this issue.
But the default gap is dropped if the yScale maximum applied manually. 
In this case, to add some gap you should increase the scale maximum value. Also, you can define required ticks manually too. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/RmHMOxz8).